# declaration and initialization of static members

Tags: c++, class, syntax, static-members

I'm new here and I'm learning C++. I can't find the answer to the following question:

There is a class `Player`. What do the following phrases declare?

```
static Player * Player::bestPlayer = NULL;
```

and I'm also confused about:

```
string &a = b;
```

Comment: The  member of static class player is assigned the value null

Comment: I strongly suggest you to learn class,pointers ,answer to this question cannot help you grasp the basics .

Comment: Try to avoid multiple questions within single question (especially when they are unrelated).

Comment: I've just verified with two different compilers: the first line you give does _not_ compile if `Player` is a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first: it's hard to imagine a case where it would
be legal.  (Perhaps if `Player` is a namespace, but even then,
the first declaration of `bestPlayer` must be within the
namespace.  And can't be a definition, since this line is
a definition.)

What is probably meant is something like:

```
class Player
{
    //  ...
    static Player* bestPlayer;
    //  ...
};
```

and then:

```
Player* Player::bestPlayer = NULL;
```

Note that the keyword `static` *must* be in the class
definition, and not on the definition of the object itself, and
that the initialization can only be on the definition of the
object.

As for the second, it declares the symbol `b` to be an alias to
`a`.  Anything you do to `a` affects `b`, and vice versa, and
anything you attempt to do will show them to be the same object.
(e.g. `&a == &b`).  This is called a reference, and while
there's rarely if ever any reason to use one as a local
variable, they are widely used as function arguments, and in
specific scenarios as return values.

Answer (score 1):

These mean:

1. Static member of type `Player*` is initialized to `NULL`. Remove the keyword `static` id the declaration is outside the class. If the declaration is inside, then remove the scope resolution operator.
2. A reference variable of type `string` is created and assigned reference of `b` as

   ```
   string b;  
   string &a = b;
   ```

Comment: Re 1: where is this declaration situated.  If it is within the class, then the name should be simply `bestPlayer`, and not `Player::bestPlayer`, and if it's outside the class (the definition of a static member), then it shouldn't have the keyword `static`.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes agreed. Thanks for your input! Modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

The first initializes a static member of class Payer to NULL (Note that member is a pointer). The second initializes a reference to a string with another string

Answer (score 0):

```
Player * Player::bestPlayer = NULL;
```

initializes `static` member `bestPlayer` of type `Player*` to `NULL`. This is placed in some `.cpp` file and it belongs to the declaration, which probably looks like this:

```
// Player.h
class Player {
public:
    static Player* bestPlayer;
    ...
};
```

and to your second question, it declares a reference `a` to `std::string` object `b`:

```
std::string b;
std::string &a = b;
```

Have a look at: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/1168156)

Comment: The line cannot be put in a cpp file as it has static keyword.

Comment: The first line cannot be put anywhere in a program that I can see.  Maybe if the code contains `namespace Player { extern static bestPlayer; } static Player* Player::bestPlayer = NULL;`, but I'm not sure you're allowed to combine `static` and `extern` on the same declaration.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I just copied the OP's code and while doing so I overlooked the fact that `static` keyword should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the first snippet is a definition of a static member "bestPlayer" of a class Player.

Static member is shared between all instances if a class. It's not a member of the object (of the instance of the class), but of the class itself.

It's often used for creating singletons (google singleton pattern).

The code in the second snippet creates a reference named "a" to the string variable "b".
Reference in c++ is something like an alias. It's similar to the pointer.

Comment: The use of the keyword `static` is not legal on the definition of a static data member.  (Probably because at namespace scope, `static` doesn't mean static lifetime, but rather internal name binding.  And class members, static or not, never have internal name binding.)